# Forbidden access to white listed isiscouch

Tags: httplib2, pythonanywhere

Im trying to reach isiscouch on my app on pythonanywhere and despite the fact that the site is whitelisted and that I'm currently a free user it just returns `HTTPError: (403, 'Forbidden')` on error log. What am I missing here?

```
response, content = httplib2.Http().request("https://-stripped-.iriscouch.com", 'GET', None, headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting the 403 from the site, then. What is in the content of the response?

Comment: Thats the stacktrace:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 390, in __negotiatehttpraise HTTPError((statuscode, statusline[2]))
HTTPError: (403, 'Forbidden') `

Comment: I`ve reached the website trough website bash using curl and got the data back, but when tried the same on a pyhon console using httplib2 I got the 403.

Comment: I made a new test `httplib2.Http().request("http://biopython.org", 'GET')` wich is another whitelisted url and tested on curl and still got 403. Do you suggest another lib to use or it is just a problem my account on pythonanywhere is facing?

Comment: This might be a bug in `httplib2`, I remember it used to have problems with HTTPS over proxies.  (PythonAnywhere uses a proxy for the free user whitelist thing.)   You might have more luck if you use `requests` instead, it doesn't have that bug.